# Preserve order with Select...Where In and lock the lines

Tags: java, sql, select

I have the following prepared statement in java:

```
with main_select as 
  (select request_id,rownum iden
   from 
    (select request_id
     from queue_requests
     where request_status = 0 and
           date_requested <= sysdate and
           mod(request_id,?) = ?
     order by request_priority desc, oper_id, date_requested)   
   where rownum < ?) 

select *
from queue_requests qr, main_select ms
where qr.request_id in ms.request_id
order by ms.iden for update skip locked;
```

It doesn't execute:

**ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.**

I'll try to explain why i need all the select statements:

- the first (inner) select obtains the data i need
- the second one limits the number of lines to a number (i can't put it in the first select, because oracle firstly limits the results and only after orders them, which is not what i want)
- the third (outside with) select preserves the order (i tried using 3 nested selects - so, no with clause - but i can't find a way to preserve the order in this case). Also, it should lock the lines in the queue_requests table, but because i selected data from the with clause, it gives the above error.

So, i want to select data from queue_requests, keep the first x lines, preserve the order of the select and lock the lines.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I realized that, in my specific case, i select data with mod, so every thread will select its own part of the table, so i can safely remove "for update skip locked". But, for the general case, in which the select does not use mod and it really needs to lock the lines, i will keep this question opened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that you want to set a lock on the result of main_select. I would just guess, that you can do `select for update` in the select in the with clause like:

```
with main_select as 
  (select request_id,rownum iden
   from (subselect)
   where rownum < ?
   for update skip locked)
```

But as I said lucky guess.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Now it says: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. I came across this error quite often and it's kinda weird because (in my opinion) it has nothing to do with the paranthesis. If i remove "for update skip locked" the error dissapears, so i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: oops.. then remove the semicolon :)

Comment: The thing is, somehow the database has to know, which rows it has to lock. If you do something like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x <= 5 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` then the result is a subset of everything in table `foo`, and the resulting rows have still the rowId which can be used to identify the rows that are ro be locked.
But I think this information is lost (a) in the with-clause or (b) on the join with the table queue_requests or (c) during sorting.

Comment: I did it from the first time :) I don't know what causes the error. Are you sure you can use for update in with clause? The outer select gets data from queue_requests and main_select, but main_select would lock queue_requests...

Comment: I'm very unsure about that, but I am really interested in why this does not work as you want it to ;)